# Actionscript: Call function from action panel in second frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am starting to learn Adobe Flash. I'm using Flash CS6.

I have a file called `test.fla` and another called `bikertest.as`

Bikertest has this code:

```
package as3.grey{
    import com.grey.utils.Console;
    //import com.grey.utils.ClickTag;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import com.greensock.TweenNano;
    import com.greensock.easing.*;
    import flash.events.*;

public class bikertest extends MovieClip {

private var mc:MC;
        private var console:Console;

public function ray():void{
    init();
    trace("hi from here");
    mc=new MC  ;
    addChild(mc);
}

....................
```

I tried:

```
import as3.grey.bikertest.as;

var t = new bikertest();

t.ray();
```

I want to be able to call `ray()` from the Action Panel in the second frame in `test.fla` . I hope this is clear. How can I do that? /Thanks!

Comment: Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't describe what the actual issue is (is it throwing a compiler or runtime error?  It is just not tracing "hi from here" etc), I can only comment on the obvious code errors:

Change this:  `import as3.grey.bikertest.as;`
to this:

```
import as3.grey.bikertest;  //(loose the `.as`)
```

And change this:  `mc=new MC   ;`
to this:

```
mc = new MC(); //(use brackets when instantiating - though the FlashPro compiler should allow it without)
```

And change this: `var t = new bikertest();`
to this:

```
var t:bikertest = new bikertest();  //so the compiler knows what kind of object t is
```

If that doesn't resolve your issue, please update your question to be more specific about what isn't working.

Also, make sure your `bikertest.as` file is the right folder: `project root (where the .fla is) -> as3 -> grey`